# Data model for Contact details

Tags: mysql, sql, data-modeling, datamodel

I need to store primary contact and secondary contact of a client in my db.
Client will have few fields and PY contact details is mandatory. Sy contact details is optional.

**Approach 1:-**

**Table 1:- client**

```
client_id
client_name
py_email
py_cell
py_phone
sy_email
sy_cell
sy_phone
```

**Approach 2:-**

**Table 1:-** client

```
client_id
client_name
py_email
py_cell
py_phone
```

**Table 2:- contact**

```
client_id
sy_email
sy_cell
sy_phone
```

**Approach 3:-**

**Table 1 :- client**

```
client_id
client_name
```

**Table 2:- contact**

```
client_id
email
cell
phone
```

Here, client will have couple of other fields.

Since, Py contact is mandatory, I prefer the 2nd approach.

Any issue with the 2nd approach?

Comment: I would go with approach 3, but add a non-nullable column on `client` called `PrimaryContactId` and nullable column called `SecondaryContactId`, and remove `client_id` from `contact`. In Postgres, you can have deferrable constraints, which makes things simpler

Comment: Cool. But with this, select query with client join returns 2 records and client details will be duplicated in both the records.

Comment: That's what Pivoting is for (or you can have an ordering column and left join twice). But otherwise how do you deal with someone who has 3 contacts?